# Global variable between event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I have a map inside my canvas.
I want to drag this map using mouse pointer.
I set global variable dragMap to false at the beginning and
set it to true when the mouse is down and then set it back to false when it's up.
For dragging I check this global variable value inside handler for mousemove event and
if it's true, I redraw the map with offset.

Written above is what I want my code to do but it doesn't work. Inside the mousemove handler dragMap varialbe is always false. When I click and drad this map my console log shows:

```
true
14 false
```

The first "true" occures from mousedown handler, the "falses" - from mosemove event.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dragMap = false;
    var startDragMapX;
    var startDragMapY;

    $("#myCanvas").mousedown(function(e){
        dragMap = true;
        startDragMapX = e.pageX;
        startDragMapY = e.pageY;
        console.log(dragMap);
        //var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        //var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    });
    $("#myCanvas").mousemove(function(e){
        console.log(dragMap);
        if(dragMap) {
            console.log(2);
            oX = e.pageX-startDragMapX;
            oY = e.pageY-startDragMapY;
            draw(ctx,1,1,oX,oY);
        }
    });         
    $("#myCanvas").mousedown(function(){
        dragMap = false;
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used mousedown instead of mouseup in the third handler

```
$("#myCanvas").mouseup(function(){
    dragMap = false;
});
```

So when the mousedown happens first the flag is set to true, then the second `mousedown` handler runs setting it to false so in `mousemove` handler you will have `dragMap == false`.

Also these variables are not `Global` variables(`window` scoped) they are [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) [scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Scope_and_the_function_stack) variables.

Answer (score 0):

your binding mousedown two times,

change

```
$("#myCanvas").mousedown(function(){
    dragMap = false;
});
```

to

```
$("#myCanvas").mouseup(function(){
    dragMap = false;
});
```

so dragmap is false when mousebutton is released

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#myCanvas").mousedown(function(){
    dragMap = false;
});
```

at the end of code must be mouseup

```
$("#myCanvas").mouseup(function(){
    dragMap = false;
});
```